# Unable to use java class which extends RealmObject as regular java objects

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, realm

I have a Recyclerview to display list of item, I am fetching the data from Realm database and storing it in a ArrayList. But when I am trying to update a particular BoxItem for a particular position it is showing me error like this.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                         Process: one.thebox.android, PID: 7236
                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.
                                                                  at io.realm.internal.Table.throwImmutable(Table.java:1138)
                                                                  at io.realm.internal.Table.checkImmutable(Table.java:924)
                                                                  at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.setLong(UncheckedRow.java:195)
                                                                  at io.realm.BoxItemRealmProxy.realmSet$quantity(BoxItemRealmProxy.java:590)
                                                                  at one.thebox.android.Models.BoxItem.setQuantity(BoxItem.java:347)
                                                                  at one.thebox.android.adapter.SearchDetailAdapter$SearchedItemViewHolder.updateQuantityInCart(SearchDetailAdapter.java:870)
                                                                  at one.thebox.android.adapter.SearchDetailAdapter$SearchedItemViewHolder.access$1900(SearchDetailAdapter.java:492)
                                                                  at one.thebox.android.adapter.SearchDetailAdapter$SearchedItemViewHolder$7.onClick(SearchDetailAdapter.java:786)
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please find few codes here- ArrayList boxes;

```
boxItem.setQuantity(quantity);
CartHelper.updateQuantityInCart(boxItem, quantity);
boxItems.get(position).setQuantity(quantity);
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Here it is showing error, unable to modify the object in the array List

BoxItem -

```
public class BoxItem extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
 private int quantity;
 @PrimaryKey
private String uuid;

 public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}
   public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
}
```

And CartHelper- Is a class which update data in Realm database-

```
 public static void updateQuantityInCart(final BoxItem boxItem, final int quantity) {
    Realm realm = TheBox.getRealm();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    BoxItem boxItem1 = realm.where(BoxItem.class).equalTo("uuid", boxItem.getUuid()).findFirst();
    if (boxItem1 != null) {
        boxItem1.setQuantity(quantity);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

And `updateQuantityInCart()` is a method in Adapter class, which is called when we want to update any item of the recyclerview. Like if we want to update the quantity of that particular item

Comment: well yes, `Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction`. And if you're using Realm 3.1.4 or newer, then a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` would handle the `notifyItemChanged()` call for you.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so you are asking me to try `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` and my current realm version is 3.1.3

Comment: @rahul  Its not clear what is boxItem / CartHelper and its updateQuantityInCart method. You should edit your question for more clarity

Comment: I may be mistaken, but you should do boxItems.get(position).setQuantity(quantity); first and then CartHelper.updateQuantityInCart(boxItem, quantity);  statement wright ?

Comment: @Stallion does not matter, because `CartHelper.updateQuantityInCart(boxItem, quantity);` actually updates the database.

but this `boxItems.get(position).setQuantity(quantity);` only updates the list data. Error is in this line and 
` boxItem.setQuantity(quantity);`

and error is mentioned above.

Comment: Realm ensures that whatever is in the database is what is in the list, and whatever is in the RealmResults or managed Proxy objects is what is in the database. It says so in https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#writes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to modify a Realm object outside of a transaction, which is not allowed. You should add `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()` in between of any updates like `CartHelper.updateQuantityInCart(boxItem, quantity);`

```
// Obtain a Realm instance
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();

//... add or update objects here ...

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Another best way to do in background thread could be:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync
```

Comment: this function CartHelper.updateQuantityInCart(boxitem,quantity) its updating the database and i am using this inside transaction.
But this two lines-
boxItems.get(position).setQuantity(quantity);
notifyItemChanged(position);  

is a part of ArrayList<BoxItem> - I am getting error here while updating a Boxitem for a particular position.

Comment: You should generally not have managed RealmProxies inside `ArrayList`, they should be in `RealmResults`.